# NullException Error in RadioButtonList when no value is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to find a way to throw an error when user doesn't select a value in dropdown list. I tried many solutions, that were provided here. But none seem to work.This is my code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == null)
            {
              //Throw error to select some value before button click
            } 

       if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == 'male')
           {
              //Step1
           }
       if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == 'female')
           {
              //Step2
           }
    }
```

tried replacing with

```
 if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == -1)
```

But that too did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: When no selection is made, what *is* the `SelectedIndex` if not `-1`?  When you debug, what's the actual value?

Comment: "RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == null" works? SelectedItem should be null.

Comment: The actuall code executes only when a radiobutton is selected, when when user clicks without a selection i get the error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object...and NO "RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value" == null does not work

Comment: i am sorry, but where do i see the SelectedIndex  in the debug section? can you point me in right direction

Comment: Google "c# debuggigng". This video occurs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-HdLtqEOog (I didn't watch this, but it seems useful for beginners)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier for you to debug if selected item is put into variable:

```
var selectedItem = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem;
if (selectedItem == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Please select");
} 
else if (selectedItem.Value == "male")
{
    // step 1
}
```

Radio buttons are specific. If nothing is selected, there is no selectedItem, thus no value of an object which doesn't exist.

*Edit: place debugger point in first line, var selectedItem =.. so you will on hover know what exact value it has.*

*Edit2: ALWAYS check if your object is not null. Your error in the comment is caused by the fact that you immediately try to access of an object property when actual object doesn't exist.*

Answer (score 1):

Quotation from comments:

> (rakesh) The actuall code executes only when a radiobutton is selected, when when user clicks without a selection i get the error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object...and NO "RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value" == null does not work

That is your way! The reason of the error is: *RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem* is null. So there is no *value*. So: Just check

```
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null) {...}
```

Edit for clarification of the discussion:

```
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null) 
{
    //Throw error to select some value before button click
} 
else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == "...") 
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: I tried. But it skips 'RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null' moves to the next condition with the same error - see pic: http://ibb.co/itapFb

Comment: It doesn't skip! It executes. But it also executes the line where the error occurs. Try "return" in the block or "else if".

Comment: Thank you! it executed multiple condition. i had to end the block after one execution. Thanks again.